# How to cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-effect

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

The page here includes a selectable FlatList. However if I select another element too fast (before the whole flatList is loaded), the error above will appear. I'm not sure which function I should put in useEffect and what return statements I should put so that it cleans up (or let the previous flatList stop loading).

The error specifically pointed out the **Item** function, as shown in the code below (unrelated codes skipped)

```
function ChampSelect({navigation, route}) {

    ...

    const Item = ({ item, onPress, weight, color}) => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
            <Image 
                source={require('../pictures/champions/' + item + '.png')}
                style= {[styles.image, color]}
            />
            <Text style={[styles.title, weight]}>
                {item}
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>    
    )


    const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        const fontWeight = item === selectedChamp ? 'bold' :'normal';
        const borderColor = item === selectedChamp ? '#6BDB5A' :'black'

        return (
            <Item 
                item={item}
                onPress={() => setSelectedChamp(item)}
                weight={{ fontWeight }}
                color = {{borderColor}}
            />
        )
    }

    ...

    return ( 

        ...
        
            <View style={{marginLeft: 48, marginTop: 40}}>
                <FlatList
                ListHeaderComponent={renderHeader}
                numColumns={3}
                horizontal={false}
                data={data}
                extraData={selectedChamp}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={item => item}
                />
            </View>

        </View>
    )
    
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your question is about `useEffect` yet it's nowhere in your code example. If you show us what your effect actually does maybe we will be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: @RonB. I didn't intend to add any effect to the page, the problem is if I select another element in the flatList too fast, the state changes before the old flatList  is done loading which causes this error. I'm not sure what function to put inside the useEffect and what return statement I should use in order to clean up the function.

Comment: You should move your `Item` component outside of your `ChampSelect` component. Defining components within other components the way you are doing here isn't a good practice.

Comment: If there is a way to cancel the old request, you should use that. Generally, that isn't any. One way to solve it them is to create a ref with some data you can check before trying to use setState.

Comment: @AqueleHugo could you please specify which data are you referring to...? Sorry I'm really stuck here

Comment: Some data to assure you are in a state where the setState would be succesful. For instance, if the problem is related to an specific component not being mounted, you could set a ref that is true when the component mounts and is false when the component unmounts. This hook may be useful, at least to give you some insight: https://github.com/jmlweb/isMounted